# how to create own array object in codeigniter?

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter

My Controller :

```
 protected function fillsess($sessdata){
     foreach($sessdata as $row){
     $d[] = $row->name; 
     }
    $this->session->setuserdata('savesess',$d);
 }

 public function show(){
  $data['names'] = $this->info->names();
  $this->fillsess($data['names']);
  $this->load->view('myview',$data);
 }
```

How can i create this structure of array in protected function fillsess()

```
   Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [name] => name1 ) [1] => stdClass Object ( [name]     => name2 ) )
```

Comment: this function is a part of my controller class , is there any style to change it without use of models in codeigniter

Comment: do you want to store objects into session?

Answer (score 2):

```
protected function fillsess($sessdata) {
    $arr = array();

    foreach($sessdata as $row) {
        $arr = (object) array(
            'name' => $row->name
        );
    }

    $this->session->setuserdata('savesess', $arr);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a function that you can use to format `array` to `object`.
it's not 100% but its a start, hope it helps.

```
function arrayToObject($array = '')
{
    //check if given data is an array
    if (is_array($array ))
    {
        //if array return object
        return (object) array_map(__FUNCTION__, $array);
    }else{
        // Return normal
        return $d;
    }
}
```